# Haskell: beginner function syntax confusion

Tags: haskell

I'm currently trying to learn Haskell, but I'm struggling with understanding the syntax. For example, take the `map` function:

```
map :: (s -> t) -> [s] -> [t]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

I understand what the function does, and that `map` has a function `f :: s -> t` as a parameter. But I read `map :: (s -> t) -> [s] -> [t]` as "map is a function which maps a function mapping from s to t to s and then to t", which is obviously wrong. Could someone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The type `(s -> t) -> [s] -> [t]` can be read in two ways. One way is to treat it as a function of two arguments, the first a function of type `s -> t` and the second a list of type `[s]`. The return value is of type `[t]`.

The other way is to understand that function arrows are right-associative, so the type is equivalent to `(s -> t) -> ([s] -> [t])`. Under this interpretation, `map` is a function that takes a function from element to element `s -> t` and turns it into a function from list to list `[s] -> [t]`.

Similarly, when using the function, you can think of `map foo xs` as applying the function `map` to two arguments `foo` and `xs`. Or, since function application is *left*-associative, you can think of it as `(map foo) xs`, applying `map` to the single argument `foo` to get back a new function which you then apply to `xs`.

Since Haskell functions are [curried](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying), these are just two ways of looking at the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to define a couple type aliases, to make it a bit more explicit what all those arrows and brackets are doing:

```hs
type F1 a b = a -> b  -- type synonym for single-argument functions
type List a = [a]  -- type synonym for lists
```

so now you can write `map`'s type signature as:

```hs
map :: F1 s t -> List s -> List t
```

which, if you're more familiar with Java or C++ or whatever, looks syntactically a bit more like:

```java
List<T> map(F1<S, T> fun, List<S> list); // applies fun to each element in list
```

So you can think of it this way: `map` takes a function and a list, and returns another list.  However, since functions are *curried* in Haskell, you don't have to pass all parameters at once.  You could get away with *partially applying* `map` to just its first argument.  So really its type signature is more like:

```java
F1<List<S>, List<T>> map(F1<S, T> fun); // returns a function that applies fun to each element in a list
```

... which, when you call `map` with just that one `fun` argument, gives you something that sort of looks like:

```java
List<T> mapFun(List<S> list); // applies fun to each element in list
```

So now back to Haskell: you can read `map :: (s -> t) -> [s] -> [t]` either as:

- "`map` takes a function from *s* to *t*, and a list of *s*, and returns a list of *t*"
- "`map` takes a function from *s* to *t*, and turns it into a function from a *list of s* to a *list of t*"

The former is fine; the latter is more helpful.

Comment: Caveat: if you *aren't* familiar with Java or whatever, better to ignore my answer entirely except for the very last bit ;)

Comment: Agreed. all the "<T>"s and "<S>"s made me thought "all no, now that i'm understanding haskell.. they change it again and/or come up with another extension" :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about "map is a function which maps a (function from s to t) over a (list of s) giving a (list of t)"?
That is a direct translation of the type signature into English (albeit not very elegant English).

Comment: Not general enough; for example, how would you translate the type signature `zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`?  The terminology "a function which maps blah over blah" is derived from what you know `map` does, not from its type signature.  For the `zipWith` example, I'd say it "takes a function from *a* and *b* to *c*, and turns it into a new function from *list of a* and *list of b* to *list of c*."

Answer (score 1):

Read the signature from the end: `-> [t]` means *returns a list of `t`*. The rest is 'regular' parameters.

So, `map` takes a function that from an `s` makes a `t`, and a list of `s`.

Now it's easy: take a function `s->t`, apply it to each element of `[s]` and the result of it is `[t]`.